What am i doing wrong to get this to plot this function?
a[x_] := Sin[x]; Manipulate[ Plot[a[x], {x, -3, 10} PlotRange ->{-2, 2}], Plot[a'[1] (x - t) + a[t], {x, t - 1, t + 1}], {t, -3, 10}]


Please provide copyable Mathematica code!

and how do i do that

Start inserting code at four spaces (see help "To create code blocks or other preformatted text, indent by four spaces or surround with groups of backticks: " for more details)

Try
    a[x_] := Sin[
  x]; Manipulate[{Plot[a[x], {x, -3, 10} , PlotRange -> {-2, 2}], 
  Plot[a'[1] (x - t) + a[t], {x, t - 1, t + 1}]}, {t, -3, 10}]


